# Is it possible to write JavaScript directly in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

New to vuejs. I am trying to write javascript directly in the vue file. Below is the code. I keep getting the following errors...

compiled with problems

```
 70:18  error  'openpopup' is defined but never used   no-unused-vars
 73:18  error  'closepopup' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
```

Html with script:

```
<template>
   <div class="customers-page">
      <h2>Customers</h2>

      <button type="add" class="add-button" onclick="openpopup()">Add</button>
      <div class="popup" id="popup">
          <h3>Input the following information</h3>

          <button type="add-customer" class="submit-customer-button" onclick="closepopup()">Submit</button>
        
        
      </div>  
   </div>

</template>

<script type="application/javascript" >
        let popup = document.getElementById("popup");

        function openpopup(){
            popup.classList.add("open-popup")
        }
        function closepopup(){
            popup.classList.remove("open-popup")
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very purpose to use `Vue` is to leverage its features for handling this type of logic reactively, Following is the snippet which can be used(vue 3 options api)

```
<template>
  <div class="customers-page">
    <h2>Customers</h2>

    <button type="add" class="add-button" @click="openpopup">Add</button>
    <!-- onclick="openpopup()" -->
    <div class="popup" :class="popupToggle ? 'open-popup' : ''">
      <h3>Input the following information</h3>

      <button type="add-customer" class="submit-customer-button" @click="closepopup">Submit</button>
      <!-- onclick="closepopup()" -->
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      popupToggle: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    openpopup() {
      this.popupToggle = true;
    },
    closepopup() {
      this.popupToggle = false;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Here the `popup` view is maintained by a state variable `popupToggle`, if you want to use something similar to `id` then you should go through `refs` [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#accessing-the-refs)

Answer (score 0):

When you use frameworks like Vue / React etc, using the native DOM is discourage (basically those `.getElementById`, `.classlist.add` or similar). One main reason is security, anyone can go to inspect and do DOM manipulations.

If you want to avoid the Options API boilerplate, you can use Composition API, which is similar to what you are doing.

Besides, if you are using conditional rendering, `v-if` is recommended instead of class binding, because the elements are not rendered if it is `false`.

```html
<template>
   <div class="customers-page">
      <h2>Customers</h2>
      <button type="add" class="add-button" @click="openPopup()">Add</button>
      <div v-if="isShowPopup" class="popup">
          <h3>Input the following information</h3>
          <button type="add-customer" class="submit-customer-button" @click="closePopup()">Submit</button>
      </div>  
   </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue' 
const isShowPopup = ref(false)// acts similar to options api data block

// here I am using arrow functions
const openPopup = () => {
  isShowPopup.value = true // in composition API, instead of using this., you use .value
}

const closePopup = () => {
  isShowPopup.value = false
}

</script>
```